# StackWatcher - Live tiles for Windows Phone 7

Tags: app, windows-phone

### Screenshot

[image]
[image]
[image]

### About

Add some glanceable Stack Exchange reputation tiles to your Windows Phone 7 home screen.  Some obvious features are yet to be built:

- More information on the user screen, maybe a reputation graph
- An inbox tile, add a screen to [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) your account
- Update tiles from the app - currently only updated by a `PeriodicTask` every 30 minutes
- More stack sites / meta sites to pick from

Full disclosure: I've entered this app into a Microsoft Australia competition [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140813071541/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dglover/archive/2012/03/30/windows-phone-apps-download-challenge-and-win-a-nokia-lumia-800-20120330.aspx).

#### License

Closed source

#### Download

You can download StackWatcher [here](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=51b12462-678c-444c-b8fb-c024d1dff08b):

### Contact

I can be reached at `stackwatcher@rogueproton.com`.

### Code

StackWatcher is written in C#.

Comment: Why do you only show those seven SE sites?

Comment: i need something better to pick the sites.  ended up settling on 7 sites because the icons fit under the search box

Comment: could you add an arrow to the end of the list that takes you to a complete scrolling list of all the SE sites? Keep the top few easily accessible but allow people who mostly use the other sites to get the value from your app?